# Find out whether a variable is used in a view in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a very complex controller with a very complex set of views and partial views that I'm trying to clean up (not written by me originally).

In the controller, it defines member variables, like:

```
@blah = "blah"
```

which I'm not sure if they are used in a view, or a partial view, or a partial view called by a partial view. Is there any way to find out?

Comment: A useless but obligatory comment: this task doesn't have an exact and general solution, as it's equal to the halting problem.

Comment: klochner, I know this variable is present in some views, but also some other controllers generate them.

Comment: @Pavel, some language implementations have conditional breakpoints. Those are break on-change generally. Can't a break on access be implemented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way to find out?

1. Write the tests for a given action.
2. Make sure they all pass.
3. Start cleaning up the code.
4. Repeat from 1 for every action you want to cleanup.

With [autotest](http://nubyonrails.com/articles/autotest-rails) it will be a matter of minutes.

Comment: exactly what I'd suggest: write tests, then refactor